# How to know which environment/network a NEAR smart-contract is deployed to (AssemblyScript)?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm doing some cross contract calls using NEAR and AssemblyScript. I would like to call different accounts based on the environment my smart-contract is deployed to. If the contract is deployed to testnet, I want to call a testnet cross-contract call. If the contract is deployed to mainnet, I want to call a mainnet cross-contract call.

```ts
export function callMetaNear(accountId: string): void {
  // how to get correct contract name based on where the contract is deployed?
  let otherContract: string = 'test.testnet';
  if(contractIsDeployedToMainnet) {
    otherContract = 'test.near';
  }


  // cross-contract call example
  const itemArgs: AddItemArgs = {
    accountId,
    itemId: "Sword +9000",
  };
  const promise = ContractPromise.create(
    otherContract,
    "addItem",
    itemArgs.encode(),
    0,
  );
  promise.returnAsResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. Better answers are welcome.

I figured we can assume the contract is deployed to mainnet if `Context.contractName` ends with ".near".

```ts
  import { Context } from 'near-sdk-core';
  ...
  
  let otherContract: string = 'test.testnet';
  if(Context.contractName.endsWith(".near")) {
    otherContract = 'test.near';
  }
```