# How to detect which network your contract is on

Tags: nearprotocol

Is it possible to detect which network (`testnet`, `mainnet` etc..) your contract is in via, for example, `env` in Rust? I have a contract that will be deployed to both testnet and mainnet and I have logic that depends on the network.

Comment: Similar question, but for AssemblyScript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663071/how-to-know-which-environment-network-a-near-smart-contract-is-deployed-to-asse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a two things you can do in this case that I could think of.

1. You could store in the state of the contract which network it lives on and then pass that into the initialization function.
2. If you wanted to use `env`, you could right split `env::current_account_id()` and check for `.testnet` at the end of the account ID.

> **Note**: This method won't work if your contract is deployed to an implicit account.

An example of the code is:

```rust
// Get this with env::current_account_id();
let str = "benji.testnet.fayyr.testnet".to_string();
// Get the split at the end of the string using `.testnet`
let split_check = str.rsplit_once(".testnet");

// Default network to mainnet
let mut network = "mainnet";
// If `.testnet` was found, make sure it was at the end of the account ID
if let Some(split) = split_check {
    if split.1.len() == 0 {
       network = "testnet";
    }
}
```